# How to revert back to 0 after reading the length of each word in a sentence

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with my code. I have a .csv file named `test.csv` which contains 3 sentences. I want to revert the count of the length back to 0 after it finishes reading the length of the words on the first sentence.

```
with open("test.csv") as e:
    text = e.read()

newtext = text.split()
words = ''
startindex = ''
lastIndex = '' 

if words is not ".":
    for words in newtext:
    startIndex = text.rfind(words)
    lastIndex = startIndex + (len(words))
    first_index = str(startIndex)
    last_index = str(lastIndex)
    print('(' + first_index + ',' + last_index + ')' + words)

    #The output would be                        #The output that i wanted
    #(36,38)My                                  #(0,2)My
    #(39,43)name                                #(3,7)name
    #(44,46)is                                  #(8,10)is
    #(18,21)bob                                 #(11,14)bob
    #(51,52).                                   #(15.16).
    #(18,21)bob                                 #(0,3)bob
    #(44,46)is                                  #(4,6)is
    #(25,27)my                                  #(7,9)my
    #(39,43)name                                #(10,14)name
    #(51,52).                                   #(15,16).
    #(36,38)My                                   and so on...
    #(39,43)name
    #(44,46)is
    #(47,50)lob
    #(51,52).
```

Because of the repetition of words its overwriting. I want it to be after the ('My name is bob.') sentence the counting of words would be back to 0.

Inside of the test.csv file:

```
My name is bob .

bob is my name . 

My name is lob .
```

Comment: Please [edit] and fix your indentation.

Comment: `words` is not defined. If there are only sentences would it be possible to post them here.

Comment: I've fixed the question. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach this problem:

```
with open("test.csv") as e:
    text = e.read()

newtext = text.split()
words = ''

currCount = 0


for words in newtext:

    toAdd = len(words)
    print "("+str(currCount)+","+str(currCount+toAdd)+")"+ words
    currCount+= toAdd+1

    if words is ".":
        currCount = 0
```

Output is as requested

```
> (0,2)My
> (3,7)name 
> (8,10)is 
> (11,14)bob 
> (15,16). 
> (0,3)bob 
> (4,6)is
> (7,9)my
> (10,14)name
> (15,16).
> (0,2)My
> (3,7)name
> (8,10)is
> (11,14)lob
> (15,16).
```